# loop in object array element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i'm using map() jquery to create a new object array 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/BKDLt/) but this code is not working

i need to have a new object array with the same name for all objects but with different number 
 so how can we point over each element in the old array and change its value , i used `value[0].number` but it didn't do the trick

**CODE**

```
  var x =[
 {name : 'mark' , number : '10'},
 {name : 'mina' , number : '15' } ,
 ]; 

 var newObject = $.map(x,function(value,index){

value.name = 'mon';
value[0].number = 12 ;
value[1].number = 11 ; 
return value ; 

  });
 console.log(newObject) ;
```

​
**Question** is how can i point to each number in the old object array and change it

Comment: If you want a different number, what's the point of setting two numbers for each element? What is the array you want in the end?

Comment: what exactly are you wanting to do? Is there another data set to use within the mapping  to help change the values, or function or???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old object is still here and is still called `x`

```
var newObject = $.map(x,function(value,index){

    value.name = 'mon';
    x[0].number = 12 ;
    x[1].number = 11 ; 
    return value ; 

});
```

Comment: Why would you set this inside `map`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this ( http://jsfiddle.net/BKDLt/1/ ), generating a new object rather than reusing the old one.

```
var x = [
    {
        name: 'mark',
        number: 10
    },
    {
        name: 'mina',
        number: 15
    }
];

var newObject = $.map(x, function(value, index) {
    return {
        name: value.name + 'mon',
        number: value.number + 1
    };
});
console.log(newObject);​
```